# Anti-Commutator of derivatives of Grassmann variables

Tags: fermions, supersymmetry, grassmann-numbers, anticommutator, superspace-formalism

How do I evaluate the anti-commutator of $\frac{\partial}{\partial\chi}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\eta}$ when both $\chi$ and $\eta$ are Grassmann variables?

Comment: ... act with them on an arbitrary function and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

As user AccidentalFourierTransform writes in a comment: *Act with them on an arbitrary function and see what happens...*

More generally, one may show that derivatives of [supernumbers](https://planetmath.org/Supernumber) $z$ and $w$, with definite Grassmann parities $|z|$ and $|w|$, respectively, supercommute:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\partial}{\partial w}~=~(-1)^{|z||w|}\frac{\partial}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} .$$